# Accessing columns and rows indexes in the same way

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Sorry for editing the question again but as I dug deeper into it I realized that it boils down to the question if I can access the values of a column and the values of a rows index in the same way. This, for me, would seem quite natural as the rows index and a column are actually very similar entities.

For example, if I define a DataFrame with a two-level rows multi-index like that:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=None, index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['A', 'B'], [1, 2]], names=['X', 'Y']))
df.insert(loc=0, column='DATA', value=[1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Which gives

```
       DATA
X  Y      

A  1     1
   2     2
B  1     3
   2     4
```

To access column values I can, e.g., use `df.DATA` or `df.loc[:, 'DATA']`. Consequently, to select all rows where DATA is 2, I can do `df.loc[df.DATA == 2, :]` or `df.loc[df.loc[:, 'DATA'] == 2, :]`.

However, to do the same operation on, say, the index column Y, this does not work. Neither `df.Y` nor `df.loc[:, 'Y']`. And therefore I can't select rows based on index values like above: `df.loc[df.Y == 2, :]` or `df.loc[df.loc[:, 'Y'] == 2, :]` do not work.

Which is a pity as this requires to write different code depending on if the column is a normal column or part of the index. Or is there another way to do that which works for both columns and indexes?

Comment: You mean X is the name of an item in the columns index or the rows index?

Comment: In the columns index.

Comment: What if you do `df['X'].loc[condition]`?

Comment: Well, sorry, when I talk about the multi-index I mean the row index. I'll try what you suggest.

Comment: Nope, gives me a key error.

Comment: Post some sample code which generates a relevant DataFrame.  Without that your question is unclear.

Comment: Did my answer help ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call `.loc[:,'Y']` reset the index and then call it i.e

```
df.reset_index().loc[:,'Y']
```

Output:

```
0    1
1    2
2    1
3    2
Name: Y, dtype: object
```

If you want to select the data based on condtion then

```
df.reset_index()[df.reset_index().Y == 2].set_index(['X','Y'])
```

Output:

```
    DATA
X Y      
A 2     2
B 2     4
```